# rake sitemap:install is not working for me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sitemap

I have tried referencing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769874/dont-know-how-to-build-task-gemsinstall) on SO, but am unable to get `rake sitemap:install`

working for me.

Background:

placed `gem 'sitemap-generator'` in my Gemfile, ran bundle install.

rails version is 4.2.0, Ruby is 2.2.

How can I ensure that I am able to install the sitemap?

Comment: can you supply some more information?  How about an error message/backtrace?

Comment: I realized the fix was a simple require 'sitemap_generator/tasks' in my rake file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to `require 'sitemap_generator/tasks'` in my Rakefile